# BQ SQL join with a table with a name that is derived from a query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have some fields that are a date. That date then is then used to look up a table with a name corresponding to the date of that field. I'm doing a join to get other fields, but the question is how to treat the field with the date as a variable that can be used then to perform the join.

Here is the example query:

```
with tab1 as (
    select 
        product_id, 
        start_date, 
    from `project.user.table`
) 

select * from tab1 inner join `project2.table2.{start_date}` as B on tab1.product_id = B.p_id
```

After suggestions I have tried the following query to tighten things up, but it is sadly not working.

```
with tab1 as (
    select 
        cast(product_id as INT64) as product_id_64, 
        cast(FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', CAST(start_date AS DATE)) as STRING) as start_date_string
        
    from `project.user.table`
) 

select * from `user2.dataset.*` b
inner join tab1 
on b._TABLE_SUFFIX = tab1.start_date_string
```

led to the following error:

```
Error running query. Cannot read field of type STRING as INT64 Field: GTIN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your table is a native BigQuery one you can try to test and use a [`wildcard`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables):

```
WITH tab1 as (
    select 
        product_id, 
        start_date, 
    from `project.user.table`
)

SELECT * 
FROM `<yourproject>.<yourdataset>.*` b
INNER JOIN tab1
ON b._TABLE_PREFIX = tab1.start_date
AND b.p_id = tab1.product_id
```

I can't test unfortunately

Comment: Thanks. Sadly I cannot make this work. I have the issue that there table names are the dates in question, so access is via project2.user.date. If I put the "." back in I get the following error: "Cannot read field of STRING as INT64 Field: GTIN"

Comment: @disruptive yes for the "." to separate dataset from table name. I forgot it, I'll edit the answer

Comment: any thoughts on the error. I've even tried casting the date into a string to make sure, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @disruptive about the error you have, I suspect it is because in your tables you have a column called `GTIN`, that has different type depending on the table. BigQuery infers this column is a `STRING`, but finds a `INT64` suddenly in one of the table

Comment: (and doesn't like it!)

Comment: what about trying `SELECT * EXCEPT(GTIN)` ?

Comment: I got further with `SELECT * EXCEPT(GTIN)`, but now I'm getting an error related to the field in the 'b' table which is `Cannot read field of type STRING as FLOAT64 Field: PRICE`.

Comment: This is the very same error for a different column. The root issue is the non-consistent schema of the different tables.. and it is not related to the question in this post. What you can do: for this question, instead of editing your question, please accept the answer if you feel it's correct and open another issue with the new problem if required (I believe you understand now where the error comes from)

Comment: Regarding what you can do, I suggest re-creating all the badly formatted tables and fix your ingestion pipeline to be sure about the data types that are stored.