# BQ join with casting on joined column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've been fighting a difficult join with a column to join on stored as a float. Plus I need to join on the table name. I've kindly been [steered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71127746/bq-sql-join-with-a-table-with-a-name-that-is-derived-from-a-query) in the right direction with the correct format, but I keep running into problems with the join. To clarify (don't ask me why, but the column entry of one (`PARENT_ID`) is a `float`). The data is historic and I cannot change these tables, but want to be able to select the appropriate table and join on the start_date and the `product_id`. To aim to make things tighter I have put casts on the fields. But I do not understand the source of the error.

```
    with tab1 as (
    select 
        cast(product_id as INT64) as product_id_64, 
        cast(FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', CAST(start_date AS DATE)) as STRING) as start_date_string
        
    from `project.user.table`
    ) 

    select * EXCEPT(GTIN, SALE_PRICE) from `user2.dataset.*` b
    inner join tab1 
    on b._TABLE_SUFFIX = tab1.start_date_string
    and tab1.product_id_64 = cast(b.PARENT_ID as INT64)
```

I then get the following error come up: `Cannot read field of type FLOAT64 as STRING Field: PARENT_ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can’t use in this query the command `_TABLE_SUFFIX`, because the limitation is that you cannot compare a column with the same name and one of them has different types. You will get this error(Cannot read field of type FLOAT64 as STRING Field: PARENT_ID).

> If a single scanned table has a schema mismatch (that is, a column
> with the same name is of a different type), the query fails with the
> error Cannot read field of type X as Y Field: column_name.

You can see all the limitations in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#limitations).